Asymptotic Behaviour of $e^{ \alpha \log{( \frac{a}{b})} \log(n)} \times \sum_{t=1}^{n/2} e^ {- \frac{2t}{3} (\log(t) - 3) }$
If $a>b>0$ and $\alpha = \frac{x+1}{2y}$ where $y>0$ and $x\geq 0$. Under which conditions the following summation is asymptotically ($n\to \infty$) upper-bounded by $ k n$ where $k$ is a positive finite constant.
$$ e^{ \alpha \log{( \frac{a}{b})} \log(n)} \times \sum_{t=1}^{n/2}   e^ {-  \frac{2t}{3} (\log(t) - 3) }$$
Thank you all for your assistance in advance.
